# How to view PIC32 UART1 output in MPLABX simulator?

Tags: uart, mplab

I am using MPLABX v1.80 , xc32 V1.21 and Microchip's sample uart code (the basic sample).

I have selected the simulator in project properties.
I have enabled UART1 for window output in project properties.

I have tried compiling using both UART1 and UART2.  However I cannot seem to find where the output goes.

The sample code is here:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC32_UART_CodeExample_041613.zip

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MPLABX environment uses UART1 and the sample code uses UART2.
I recompiled after changing the UART_MODULE_ID to UART1 in uart_basic.c and now MPLABX displays a UART 1 Output tab with the output.